# VM Images with existing virtual network?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I have created a VM image (classic). When I want to create a new vm based on the image I cannot add this vm to an existing virtual network.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could. Please refer to the following steps:

1.Click NEW in the bottom toolbar and select Virtual Machine->From Gallery

[image]

2.Select **MY IMages** from the right hand menu and then select the correct image:

[image]

3.Give the VM a name and choose the size VM you require; then click next

4.Once on Tab number 3 select Create a new Cloud Service and then select your VNET under Region/affinity/virtual Network and then select the Virtual Network.

[image]

Update: You also could create VM by using image on new Azure Portal.

1.Find VM Images(Classic) on new Azure Portal.
[image]

2. Create VM by using the image

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the information. The Problem is I am using the new Portal. And also I created the Image with premium storage, so that I cannot use it in the old portal (it always says that the machine cannot use premium storage)